# After syncing media images from S3, my magento site got blundered

Tags: magento2, aws

I am syncing my media folder from S3 cloud front, I changed the path in Base URL for User Media Files and gave proper path, but after that my site layout is not proper, it got blundered even though images are properly coming from S3, i checked the path through inspecting. you can see my staging site https://staging.ihouzit.com and get an idea what it has become.
Remember its just media files imported on S3 and not static files